# Bi-LSTM with Keras : dimensions must be equal but are 7 and 300

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am creating for the first time a bilstm with keras but I am having difficulties. So that you understand, here are the steps I have done:

1. I created an embedding matrix with Glove for my x ;

```
def create_embeddings(fichier,dictionnaire,dictionnaire_tokens):
    with open(fichier) as file:
        line = file.readline()
        max_words = max(dictionnaire_tokens.values())+1 #1032
        max_size_dimensions = 300
        emb_matrix = np.zeros((max_words,max_size_dimensions))
        for item,count in dictionnaire_tokens.items():
            try:
                vecteur = dictionnaire[item]
            except:
                pass
            if vecteur is not None:
                emb_matrix[count]= vecteur
        return emb_matrix
```

2. I did some one hot encoding with my y's;

```
def one_hot_encoding(file):
    with open(file) as file:
        line = file.readline()
        liste = []
        while line:
            tag = line.split(" ")[1]
            tag = [tag]
            line = file.readline()
            liste.append(tag)
    one_hot = MultiLabelBinarizer()
    array = one_hot.fit_transform(liste)
    return array
```

3. I compiled my model with keras

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional
model = Sequential()

embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim=1031 + 1,
                                    output_dim=300,
                                    weights=[embedding_matrix],
                                    trainable=False)
model.add(embedding_layer)

bilstm_layer = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=300, return_sequences=True))
model.add(bilstm_layer)
model.add(Dense(300, activation="relu"))
#crf_layer = CRF(units=len(self.tags), sparse_target=True)
#model.add(crf_layer)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics='acc')
model.summary()
```

```
Input of my embedding layer (embedding matrix) : 

[[ 0.        0.        0.       ...  0.        0.        0.      ]
 [ 0.        0.        0.       ...  0.        0.        0.      ]
 [ 0.        0.        0.       ...  0.        0.        0.      ]
 ...
 [-0.068577 -0.71314   0.3898   ... -0.077923 -1.0469    0.56874 ]
 [ 0.32461   0.50463   0.72544  ...  0.17634  -0.28961   0.29007 ]
 [-0.33771  -0.24912  -0.032685 ... -0.033254 -0.45513  -0.13319 ]]
```

4. I train my model. However when I want to train it, I get the following message: ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 7 and 300 for '{{node binary_crossentropy/mul}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](binary_crossentropy/Cast, binary_crossentropy/Log)' with input shapes: [?,7], [?,300,300].

My embedding matrix was made with glove 300d so it has 300 dimensions. While my labels, I have only 7 labels. So I have to make my x and y have the same dimensions but how? Thank you!!!

Comment: In BidirectionalLSTM set return_sequences = False. Or Add an Input Layer to the beginning of the model. the error you are getting because of these two reasons.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer but I get the following error message : Node: 'sequential_10/embedding_37/embedding_lookup'
indices[15,9] = -1 is not in [0, 1032)
  [[{{node sequential_10/embedding_37/embedding_lookup}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_22756

Comment: Your inputs contain negative numbers which are not in your embeddings, this is what he is saying to you, so try to exclude the negative embeddings or try another method. LOOK UP the INDEX of [15,9] which should definitely contain a negative number, but your embeddings don't.

Comment: I don't understand because my embedding matrix was created with the dataset that I later use to train

Comment: Well, keras.layers.Embeddings do not support negative numbers or numbers which are not included in your vocabulary so try to exclude negative numbers.

Comment: But how is that possible since I use embed_matrix for the embeddings layer and for training? i.e. I have exactly the same vocabulary? I'm really sorry, if I'm saying something wrong or if I'm having trouble understanding but it's all new to me, I'm looking for what I did wrong because I think I did all the right steps...

Comment: The input which you are passing to an embedding layer shouldn't contain negative numbers. So, if it is possible edit your question and show me your input.

Comment: It's done :) Indeed, I have negative vectors but that's normal right?

Comment: *Then don't pass the inputs from keras.embeddings because your data is already encoded, pass it directly to the keras model.

Comment: Thank you!! For that, I have to create a layer myself? Because if I delete embedding_layer et make "model.add(embedding_matrix), they say : The added layer must be an instance of class Layer.

Comment: Add, a Input() layer in the beginning and then pass that input layer to a BiLSTM(). Also, Upvote my comments if they were insightful. thanks.

Comment: I have made this modification : initial_layer= Input(embedding_matrix) but I have a error message (again) : TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index. Thank you for your patience :)

Comment: add shape not the matrix ..., like this; keras.layers.Input(shape=embedding_matrix.shape)

Comment: Actually the shape here keras.layers.input(shape= ()) #Should be the same as your input shape.

Comment: Yes sorry ... Can I bother you one last time? I put this: bilstm_layer = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=300, return_sequences=False))(initial_layer) but it still doesn't work, I'm told I need a layer class instance. In any case a big thank you for your help that made me move forward!

Comment: First, tell me what your input_x shape and y shape are... Then I can only help you.

Comment: input_x : (1032,300)
input_y: (1032,7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
keras.backend.clear_session()
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional
model = Sequential()

_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(300,1))
model.add(_input)
bilstm_layer = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=300, return_sequences=False))
model.add(bilstm_layer)
model.add(Dense(7, activation="relu")) #here 7 is the number of classes you have and None is the batch_size
#crf_layer = CRF(units=len(self.tags), sparse_target=True)
#model.add(crf_layer)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics='acc')
model.summary()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh tank you very much!!! I don't know why I've put 300 to the layer Dense... Thank you for the explanations and also for the patience!!